# change window manager colour with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

when I create a tkinter window, the window manager is yellow. Is there any way I could change it to grey or black?

example:

```py
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
#command to change window manager colour
root.mainloop()
```

I use macOSX Mojave and here is an example of the window manager being yellow:

[image]

Comment: Did you say, **only** windows created by `tkinter` have `yellow` background in the windows decoration?

Comment: @stovfl yes, only tkinter windows have this windows decoration

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Tkinter doesn't have any control over the border drawn by the window manager.

There might be some platform-specific way to do it, but no way to do it just with Tkinter alone.

Comment: look at the added image, are you aware of such a behavior at `macos Mojave`

Comment: @stovfl: no, I've never seen that behavior.